# Custom inline list_filter in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I was wondering if it's possible to have a filter over inline fields in the change_list template.

I have this models:

```
class VisitaVirtual(models.Model):
    poi = models.ForeignKey(Poi)
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, verbose_name=_(u'Cliente'))
    titulo = models.CharField(_(u'Título'), max_length=200)
    observacoes = models.TextField(_(u'Observações'), null=True, blank=True)
    exclusivo = models.BooleanField(_(u'Exclusivo'), default=False)
    remover = models.BooleanField(_(u'Remover'), default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_(u'Criado em'), auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(_(u'Modificado em'), auto_now=True, editable=False)

class FicheiroVisitaVirtual(models.Model):
    visita_virtual = models.ForeignKey(VisitaVirtual, verbose_name=_(u'Visita virtual'))
    ficheiro = models.FileField(_(u'Ficheiro'), upload_to='multimedia/visitas_virtuais/ficheiros/')
    tipo = models.CharField(_(u'Tipo'), max_length=10, null=True, blank=True, choices=TIPO_VV)
    linguagem = models.CharField(_(u'Linguagem'), choices=LANGUAGES, max_length=2)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_(u'Criado em'), auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(_(u'Modificado em'), auto_now=True, editable=False)
```

and my admin.py looks like this:

```
class FicheiroVisitaVirtualModelInlines(admin.TabularInline):
    model = FicheiroVisitaVirtual
    extra = 3
    list_filter = ['tipo']


class VisitaVirtualAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['titulo', 'cliente', 'remover', 'exclusivo', 'created', 'updated']
    list_filter = ['created']
    search_fields = ['titulo']
    ordering = ['titulo']
    raw_id_fields = ['poi', 'cliente']
    inlines = [FicheiroVisitaVirtualModelInlines]
```

I need to have a filter in tipo field which so I can filter VisitaVirtual which have FicheiroVisitaVirtual of some time.

Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

You can use fields of related models in `list_filter` using the `<related_manager>__<related field>` syntax:

```
class VisitaVirtualAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ['ficheirovisitavirtual_set__tipo', ]
     (...)
```